# Can a Cassandra / CQL3 column family have a composite partition key?

Tags: cassandra

CQL 3 allows for a "compound" primary key using a definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE timeline (
    user_id varchar,
    tweet_id uuid,
    author varchar,
    body varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tweet_id)
);
```

With a schema like this, the partition key (storage engine row key) will consist of the `user_id` value, while the `tweet_id` will be compounded into the column name. What I am looking for, instead, is for the partition key (storage engine row key) to have a composite value like user_id:tweet_id. Obviously I could do something like `key = user_id + ':' + tweet_id` in my application, but is there any way to have CQL 3 do this for me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, yes you can. That functionality was added in this ticket:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4179

The format for you would be:

```
CREATE TABLE timeline (
    user_id varchar,
    tweet_id uuid,
    author varchar,
    body varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, tweet_id))
);
```

Comment: Good to know!  I updated my answer above to avoid confusion--and upvoted yours. :)

Comment: And thus available in Cassandra 1.2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

Until 1.2 comes out, the answer is no.  The partition key will always be the first component.  As you said, the way to do this would be to create the composite key yourself.  You shouldn't shy away from this as it's actually quite common.